# Random Numberr in Array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to  create an array of 30 random integers and prints it on the screen 10 per line. The random integers will be from 0 to 100. However, I got stuck and it have not been working right way.

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static final int SS = 30;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      RandomNumber(100,1);
    }

    private static void RandomNumber(int max, int min){
        int[] n = new int[SS];
        for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++){
            n[i]=(int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < SS;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            System.out.print(n[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

### Output

> 38383838383838383838626262626262626262624343434343434343434371717171717171717171777777777777777777773737373737373737373768686868686868686868818181818181818181817979797979797979797974747474747474747474737373737373737373735050505050505050505017171717171717171717787878787878787878785555555555555555555544444444443939393939393939393977777777777777777777454545454545454545458383838383838383838356565656565656565656606060606060606060602727272727272727272717171717171717171717777777777777777777776565656565656565656517171717171717171717111111111111111111111212121212121212121272727272727272727272

Comment: your 'println' line must be the last statement of your "for i" scope(instead of after, move it up). And your 'print' statement should include a space after or before your integer to avoid confusion between values. And for the second i loop, the i increment (i++) shoud be on the print instruction not on the for.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
private static void RandomNumber(int max, int min){
    int[] n = new int[SS];
    for (int i = 0; i < SS; i++){
        n[i]=(int)(Math.random() * max) + min;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < SS;i++){
        if(i%10 == 0) System.out.print("\r\n");
        System.out.print(n[i] + " ");
    }
 }
```

`System.out.print(n[i] + " ");` print your numbers in line with space

`if(i%10 == 0) System.out.print("\r\n");` start new line if iteration variable i equals 10 and 20 (divisible by 10 without remainder)

Comment: Maybe add a description of what you did rather than just "try it"?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`java.util.Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to generate the random integer. Using `101` as the parameter will give you a random integer from `0` to `100`.
2. Use a nested loop to print `10` numbers in a line and then break the line.
3. I have also used a `boolean firstPrinted` to print a comma after each number in a line but not after the last number in the line.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int ALL = 30;
        final int LINE = 10;
        final int LIMIT = 100;
        boolean firstPrinted;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= ALL / LINE; i++) {
            firstPrinted = false;
            for (int j = 1; j <= LINE; j++) {
                int r = rand.nextInt(LIMIT + 1);
                if (firstPrinted) {
                    System.out.print(",");
                }
                System.out.print(r);
                firstPrinted = true;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
53,72,78,45,47,70,8,65,42,7
57,24,81,10,21,43,78,32,37,42
58,18,42,56,17,82,51,100,99,50
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not the most efficient, but it shows a simple way to break up the different lines by using for loops.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;
class Foo {     
 

 
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Random rand = new Random(); 
   
      for(int i=0; i <=10; i++ ){
         int printThis = rand.nextInt(100);
         System.out.print(printThis + " ");
      }

      System.out.println(); //for formatting

      for(int i=0; i <=10; i++ ){
         int printThis = rand.nextInt(100);
         System.out.print(printThis + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();

      for(int i=0; i <=10; i++ ){
         int printThis = rand.nextInt(100);
         System.out.print(printThis + " ");
      }
      
   
   }
    
}
```

Outputs:

```
88 28 50 43 28 18 33 64 67 6 52 
90 85 42 21 27 83 57 68 48 41 53 
33 23 83 4 72 35 9 32 85 27 87
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break up the logic of generating and printing the numbers.

You would add a new line when the mod of the current number is equal to the max numbers per line minus one.

I also added `printf` into the mix to format the integers take up two whole numbers.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printArray(randomNumbers(30, 100, 1), 10);
    }

    private static int[] randomNumbers(int count, int max, int min) {
        int[] result = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            result[i] = (int) (Math.random() * max) + min;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void printArray(int[] arr, int perLine) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", arr[i]);
            if (i % perLine == perLine - 1) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```